# Como dar formato a un datetime c#

Tags: c#

necesito pasar un datetime en xml al siguiente formato:

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]

Ahorita solo le pongo datetime.now pero no me lo pone con ese formato

Answer (score 1):

Para aplicar formato usas

[Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

[Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

entonces seria

```
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;

string fechaFormat = fecha.ToString("O");
```

Analiza los formatos `estándar` porque ya tienes esta reglas que necesitas